# Наследование от абстрактного базового класса

Tags: c++, классы, наследование

Не получается создать экземпляр класса, унаследованного от чисто абстрактного класса, говорит что наследник тоже абстрактный, хотя все виртуальные методы реализованы. Буду признателен за помощь

-----------------АБСТРАКТНЫЙ КЛАСС------------------

```
#ifndef PAIR_H

#define PAIR_H

class Pair
{
    public:
        Pair();
        virtual ~Pair() {}

        virtual void sum() = 0;
        virtual void diff() = 0;
        virtual void multi() = 0;
        virtual void division() = 0;

    protected:

    private:
};

#endif
```

---

---------------ХЕДЕР НАСЛЕДНИКА-----------------

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H

#define COMPLEX_H

#include "Pair.h"

class Complex : public Pair
{
    public:
        Complex();
        ~Complex();

        double get_real();
        double get_imagionary();

        void set_real(double newReal);
        void set_imagionary(double newImagionary);

        void sum(const Complex& n1);
        void diff(const Complex& n1);
        void multi(const Complex& n1);
        void division(const Complex& n1);

    private:
        double real;
        double imagionary;
};

endif // COMPLEX_H
```

---

------------РЕАЛИЗАЦИЯ МЕТОДОВ НАСЛЕДНИКА------

```
#include "Complex.h"
#include "Pair.h"
Complex::Complex()
{
    real = 0;
    imagionary = 0;
}

Complex::~Complex()
{
    //dtor
}

void Complex::sum (const Complex& n1)
{
    this->real += n1.real;
    this->imagionary += n1.imagionary;
}

void Complex::diff (const Complex& n1)
{
    this->real -= n1.real;
    this->imagionary -= n1.imagionary;
}

void Complex::multi (const Complex& n1)
{
    this->real = this->real * n1.real - this->imagionary * n1.imagionary;
    this->imagionary = this->real * n1.imagionary + this->imagionary * n1.real;
}

void Complex::division (const Complex& n1)
{
    this->real = (this->real * n1.real + this->imagionary * n1.imagionary) / (n1.real * n1.real + n1.imagionary * n1.imagionary);
    this->imagionary = (n1.real * this->imagionary - this->real * n1.imagionary) / (n1.real * n1.real + n1.imagionary * n1.imagionary);
}

double Complex::get_real()
{return real;}

double Complex::get_imagionary()
{return imagionary;}

void Complex::set_real(double newReal)
{real = newReal;}

void Complex::set_imagionary(double newImagionary)
{imagionary = newImagionary;}
```

Comment: методы в базовом классе не принимают параметров, а в наследнике у них есть параметры. Следовательно методы базового класса остались абстрактными, а в наследнике вы добавили новые.

Comment: в наследнике переопределяемые методы помечайте ключевым словом `override`. Это поможет избежать подобных оплошностей.

Comment: Не помогает override компилятор утверждает что override есть а переопределения нету

Comment: Всё правильно, компилятор подсказывает, что вы не переопределяете там, где хотели бы... Это и есть цель override

Comment: Я начинаю путаться) я переопределяю виртуальный метод с параметром с override. а меня в ответ компилятор шлет далеко и надолго

Comment: В cpp есть понятие перегрузки функций. Функции с одинаковым именем, но разными сигнатурами - разные функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понимаю физического смысла класса Pair, но попробую предложить вот что:

В базовом классе добавляете виртуальные методы:

```
virtual double getFirst()=0;
virtual double getSecond()=0;
virtual void setFirst(double)=0;
virtual void setSecond(double)=0;
```

Методы операций определяете в базовом классе:

```
void Pair::sum(const Pair& op) {
  setFirst(getFirst()+op.getFirst());
  setSecond(getSecond()+op.getSecond());
};
```

В дочернем классе реализовываете get/set элементов пары:

```
double Complex::getFirst(){return real;} // ...
```

В итоге: есть наследование, переопределение и всё работает)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Неплохое решение, если уж никак не получится базовый класс сделать полностью асбрактным без реализации ;-)

Comment: Ну, никто вам не мешает перенести реализацию операций в дочерний класс с параметрами `Pair`

Comment: В целом да, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Ну да, в абстрактном вы объявляете функции **без параметров**, а в конкретном - **с параметрами**. Но это же разные функции!

А

```
virtual void sum() = 0;
virtual void diff() = 0;
virtual void multi() = 0;
virtual void division() = 0;
```

так и остаются не перекрытыми, а класс `Complex`, соответственно, абстрактным...

Comment: Что мне тогда передать в качестве параметров в метод, у меня же не один класс наследник, а много. Передача параметра Pair& тоже не помогает. Мб туплю, вечер уже думать тяжело)

Comment: Вы определитесь для чего вам методы в базовом классе и вообще наследование. Потомки оперируют только с себе подобными или с братьями тоже? В первом случае наследование ни к чему, во втором надо реализовывать методы с Pair

Comment: Только с себе подобными. Но по заданию нужно реализовать наследование, вот сижу и голову ломаю как это запилить